# Assembly language, accessing bytes of memory

Tags: memory, assembly, register

I have some memory address 0x00000100 that I want to read from. The lower 4 bits read from this address indicates the states of 4 buttons - So bit 0 shows the state of button 0, bit 1 shows the state of button 1, etc. My question is- How can I find determine the state of button 0 and button 1 in assembly language? I want to know when button 0 and button 1 are high.

I am using a MiteFPGA processor, and Xilinx Vivado, on a basys 3 board. I am using the MiteASM assembler.

Comment: If button 1 is high I want t increment a counter, whereas if button 0 is high, I want to reset it. I think I have the other details of assembly language sorted, but it's this reading from particular bytes of memory address 0x100 that is getting me.

Comment: You don't want to read specific bytes, but specific **bits**. I can't find information on your MiteFPGA CPU. Please supply some documentation.

Comment: The typical way is to read the byte with the interesting bits into an ALU register, then bit-test on them. Depending on the CPU, it may also be possible to have this bit-test done directly with memory, or there aren't bit-test instructions which means you had to AND the ALU register against a mask and check the zero flag.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the 'lw' operation (load word) to grab 0x100 it has the format 'lw $rt SignImm($rs)'. Then you need to do an 'and' operation with the appropriate bit mask to extract the state of that bit. The and op is in the form 'and $rd, $rs, $rt'.

So say the bottom 4 bits are: 1001, and you AND that with 1000. The result will be 1000, telling you that the 4th bit is a 1.